# Like a cell complex but characteristic maps send n-cell boundary to other n-cells

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

Recall that a cell complex is a topological space $X$ that satisfies the following definition:

> $X$ decomposes as a union of open cells of varying dimensions. For
>   each cell $C$ of dimension $n\geq 1$ there is a continuous map $f\colon D^n \to X$ (called the characteristic map of $C$) that restricts to a homeomorphism $(D^n)^{int} \to C$ and
>   maps $\partial D$ into a union of cells in $X$ of dimension $<n$.

I have a topological space that by construction satisfies all the parts of this definition except for one: it has a decomposition into cells and each cell has an obvious characteristic map, but the characteristic maps map the boundary of each n-cell into a union of other n-cells (in fact, all the cells in the space I am considering are of the same dimension $\geq 1$).

Does this variation of cell complex have a name? Is there a straightforward way to turn this space into a cell complex?

**Edit:** I changed the question from being about CW complexes to being about cell complexes. The space in question does satisfy axioms (C) and (W) from Lee, given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42005/precise-official-definition-of-a-cell-complex-and-cw-complex), which is the reason I originally asked about CW complexes: the space satisfies the definition of a CW complex (following Lee) except for one part of the definition of a cell complex.

Comment: The question is not really precise. You can build a space in finitely many steps by attaching cells in the way you decribe -  but what does this mean? Start with one $0$-cell and attach other $0$-cells as described? Then the $0$-skeleton always is a singleton. Or do you allow to start with an arbitrary discrete space? Similarly in higher dimensions: You must attach at least one $n$-cell to the $(n-1)$-skeleton.

Comment: @PaulFrost I realize, in trying to answer your question, that my question is really about the definition of cell complexes, not CW complexes. Now it should be perfectly clear.

Comment: You write "the characteristic maps map the boundary of each $n$-cell into a union of interiors of other $n$-cells". What do you mean by the interior of an $n$-cell? Just a normal *open* $n$-cell or the topological interior of a closed $n$-cell?

Comment: @PaulFrost Of course, the cells are open, so the interior of a cell is the cell itself. I'm sorry for adding the unnecessary extra word. I removed it.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example (say, with two cells)?

Comment: I don't see how concrete examples will help to answer my question. Part 1 asks for a definition or terminology, and part 2 asks for something very general.

Comment: I still do not really understand what kind of space you mean. "All the cells in the space I am considering are of the same dimension $\ge 1$". So it has open $n$-cells for some $n \ge 1$ but **no** lower- and higher-dimensional cells? In that case $X$ is the disjoint union of open $n$-cells $e_\alpha$. The characteristic
maps $\phi_\alpha : D^n \to X$ for $e_\alpha$ must then map $S^{n-1}$ into the $\bigcup_{\beta \ne \alpha} e_\beta$. This seems somewhat strange, but of course it is not impossible.